# SQL Server - contar registros por combinação

Tags: sql-server

Pessoal estou precisando fazer uma consulta no sql server de forma que ela identifique pra mim quando as combinações 1,2 e 3 ou 2 e 3 da coluna "desc" estejam presentes para valores repetidos da coluna "cod" o resultado deve ser retornado como 1 para encontrado e 0 não encontrado. Alguem sabe como é possivel fazer esta consulta? Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não ficou muito claro, vc quer retornar uma pesquisa onde o desc for igual ao id?

Comment: Não, o "id" é a resposta olhe apenas para as colunas "cod" e "desc" quando as letras forem repetidas em "cod" quero verificar se dentro das repetições existem as combinações mencionadas. No exemplo B repete e tem a combinação 1,2 e 3 na coluna "desc", C possui a combinação 2 e 3 e por fim H possui a combinação 1,2 e 3. Obrigado

Comment: Tentando explicar de uma forma mais clara, quero que toda vez que tiver uma repetição das letras na coluna "cod" seja verificado na coluna "desc" as se os números 1 e 2 e 3 não importando a ordem esteja contido dentro das repetições isso vale também para a combinação 2 e 3 não importando a ordem. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma query para analisar as combinações usando `STUFF`, veja esse link: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation

E a partir dessa query, analisar os valores combinados para retonar o ID com `CASE`.
A query ficará assim:

```
WITH combinado (cod, descr) 
     AS (SELECT cod, 
                -- combina os valores 1,2 e 3, agrupado por cod
                Stuff((SELECT ', ' + Cast(descr AS CHAR(1)) 
                       FROM   teste AS t2 
                       WHERE  t2.cod = t.cod 
                       ORDER  BY descr 
                       FOR xml path(N'')), 1, 2, N'') AS descr 
         FROM   teste t) 
SELECT cod, 
       descr, 
       CASE descr 
         WHEN '1, 2, 3' THEN 1 
         WHEN '2, 3' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS ID 
FROM   combinado
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando aqui nesse *fiddle*: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/da106/15

Comment: Muito obrigado colega ajudou muito. abs